# Implement OnRaisePropertyChanged on partial class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I used entityframework to generate classes from database. In some of these classes, I'd like to inherit from PropertyChangeBase to implement function OnRaisePropertyChanged for some properties.
Therefore, I modified on some generated classes. Ex

```
public partial class MyGeneratedClass : PropertyChangeBase
{
        private DateTime _lastUpdatedDate;
        public System.DateTime LastUpdatedDate
        {
            get { return _lastUpdatedDate; }
            set
            {
                _lastUpdatedDate = value;
                OnRaisePropertyChanged("LastUpdatedDate");
                OnRaisePropertyChanged("LastUpdatedDateFormat");
            }
        }
}
```

Because everytime I update my entity, all my code will be overwrited. Implement in the partial class will raise an compile error. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: The entityframework already provides methods to override when a property changes so you can tap into that.

Answer (score 0):

The EntityFramework gives `partial` methods that can be fully implemented.
As all generated entities are also `partial` classes, you can basically extend your entity and do what ever you need to do there.

See these articles for example:
[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/471643/AplusBeginner-27splusTutorialplusonplusPerformingp) and [P is for partial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2009/04/20/p-is-for-partial-method.aspx)

You could then implement the interface and not worry about having the code wiped out every time you update the designer file to reflect changes.