# Add a dimension to an existing Array of Array Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Assuming i have an array of People (it is an entity in the Database, generated via the edmx).

I want to add a new field to the entity (an unbound calculated field).

What should i do?
Create a new class that will inherit from the People entity with the new field ?
Using partial class ?
How to fill the new colum in the array ?

Thanks
Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity framework generates partial classes for all entity objects.  You can add whatever properties you like by adding them to the partial class with the same name as the generated class. As @Gervasio mentioned you would have to manually populate the property through code. I posted a similar answer here: [Implement OnRaisePropertyChanged on partial class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945251/implement-onraisepropertychanged-on-partial-class/17945606#17945606)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a partial class and add the property there. However, in order to use it in linq queries, you need to fetch the elements from the db. So, you could do this

```
entities.People.ToList().Sum(p=>p.CalculatedField);
```

While this wouldn't work

```
entities.People.Sum(p=>p.CalculatedField);
```

B/c there's no way for linq to translate that into SQL